# How to extract Data from AngularFire2 Function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, angularfire2

I am attempting to instantiate a variable using an AngularFire2 function. My function is `authorizeUser()`, however when I attempt assigning the result of that function to `this.user` it is returned as 'undefined' in the console window.

```
import  { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';

import { SignupService } from '../../../services/signup/signup.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'console',
  templateUrl: './console.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./console.component.css']
})

export class ConsoleComponent implements OnInit {

  signups: any;
  user : any;

  constructor(
    public af: AngularFire,
    private signupService: SignupService
  ) {}

  getSignupsList() {
    this.signupService.getSignups().subscribe(signups => {
      this.signups = signups;
    });
  }

  authorizeUser() {
    this.af.auth.subscribe( afData => {
      this.user = afData.auth.email;
      });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getSignupsList();
    this.authorizeUser();
    console.log(this.user);

  }

  login() {
    this.af.auth.login();
  }

}
```

However, if I console log within the promise, I get the proper output I am seeking :

```
authorizeUser() {
    this.af.auth.subscribe( afData => {
      this.user = afData.auth.email;
      console.log(this.user);
      });
  }
```

What am I missing here? I want to be able to assign the output of `afData.auth.email` to a global variable: `user`

Comment: You don't have a promise, you have an observable. It works inside the callback to the observable because *that happens when the data has arrived*. I'd advise reading up on basics of async and callbacks before continuing. Also that's not a global variable.

Comment: I agree that I need to do a little more research within the subject, but **user** is not a global variable? How so? I come from a strong Java background and that seems as if it's global.

Comment: could you log the `afData` to see what's there?

Comment: What version of `AngularFire2` are you using? It seems to be an older version.

Answer (score 0):

The user variable is scoped to the component. It's not global.